# Qt LCD display not working

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to make the output of an http get connection stream to an lcd screen (a future http stock ticker), once connected. My code errors with “C:\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\httpGET\mainwindow.cpp:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘QLCDNumber::display() ui->lcdNumber->display()” I am unsure how to update display() properly

//mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QImageReader>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    ui->lcdNumber->display(10);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::connect()
{
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));

    //ui->lcdNumber->display(10);
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));

}

void MainWindow::requestPage(){
    QUrl url("http://www.google.com");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void MainWindow::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply){
    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
        QImage pic = imageReader.read();
        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
        QString string(bytes); // string
    }

    else
    {

    }

}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    connect();
    requestPage();
}
```

//mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:
    void connect();
    void requestPage();
    void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply);
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
private slots:

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager* nam;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mConnect;
    mConnect.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

moving display() fixed the lcd output issue.

```
if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
{
    QImageReader imageReader(reply);
    QImage pic = imageReader.read();
    QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
    QString string(bytes); // string
    ui->lcdNumber->display(string);
}
```